# Issue with output of WooCommerce hooks on cart and checkout page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart, hook-woocommerce, checkout

I am trying to add some text below the applied coupon on my cart page, but for some reason, I can only get it to display above the table, as per the screenshot.

[image: screenshot of cart]

I even created a fresh install with the twentytwentyone theme, and no other plugins installed besides woocommerce.

These are the code that I am using:

```php
add_action('woocommerce_cart_totals_before_shipping', 'bb_before_shipping');
function bb_before_shipping() {
    echo 'woocommerce_cart_totals_before_shipping';
}
```

And

```php
add_action('woocommerce_before_cart_totals', 'apply_product_on_coupon');
function apply_product_on_coupon() {
    global $woocommerce;
    if ( ! empty( $woocommerce->cart->applied_coupons ) ) {
        echo 'woocommerce_before_cart_totals';
    }       
}
```

---

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the correct hook for the cart page, but the output is part of a HTML table.

So you get:

```php
// Cart
function action_woocommerce_cart_totals_before_shipping() {
    echo '<tr><td>woocommerce_cart_totals_before_shipping</td></tr>';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_totals_before_shipping', 'action_woocommerce_cart_totals_before_shipping' );

// Checout
function action_woocommerce_review_order_before_shipping() {
    echo '<tr><td>woocommerce_review_order_before_shipping</td></tr>';  
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_shipping', 'action_woocommerce_review_order_before_shipping' );
```